# How to populate listview with bitmap image using simple adapter

Tags: android, bitmap

Data is not added to listview. its show a error without image view its add the id of its image to list view but when i pass a image string to image view its give an error

```
   JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            jsonarray=json_data.getJSONArray("image");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject c=jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                id=c.getString("id");
                image=c.getString("image");//receiving the json blob image data


                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String imaged = new String(decodedString);
                //bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                //////

                HashMap<String,String> mydata=new HashMap<String, String>();
                mydata.put("id", id);
                mydata.put("image",imaged);

                arraylist.add(mydata);

                Log.w("id", id);
                Log.e("11", "json data");

            }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String from[]={"id",,"image"};
    int to[]={R.id.id,R.id.pimage};
    smp=new         

   SimpleAdapter(prescriptionlist.this,arraylist,R.layout.prescription_list_row,from,to);
    patientlistdata.setAdapter(smp);


}
```

json data of image whre the typr of image in mysql is blob

```
 {"image":     [{"id":"1","image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/........
 {"id":"2","image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABA.........
```

logcat of program

```
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268): Process: com.example.drprescription, PID: 3268
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at        

android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at     

android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at        

    com.example.drprescription.prescriptionlist$viewprescription.onPostExecute(prescriptionlist.java:157)     10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):   at  

        com.example.drprescription.prescriptionlist$viewprescription.onPostExecute(prescriptionlist.java:1)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at     

android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at 

android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at 

android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at 

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at 

android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native     

Method)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at     

java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-10 16:35:40.470: E/AndroidRuntime(3268):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: second element in array of string from is null.Remove semi colon and check.

Comment: A little off topic but embedding image data into json may cause huge performance problems. You might want to use a async image loading library (Universal Image Loader, Volley, Picasso, Aquery are some examples)

Comment: Ajay thakur.i removed that semicolon but the error is same.